# Uninitialized constant WebHook::Endpoint when running zeitwerk test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upgrade, factory-bot, zeitwerk

I've recently started the upgrading process of my app to use Rails 6. Some of it is very smooth, some of it not.

The problem I am facing right now is that in a factory bot we define:

```
factory :webhook_endpoint, class: Webhook::Endpoint do
   ...
end
```

When running rails zeitwerk:check it simply throws Uninitialized constant WebHookEndpoint.

The module and class is defined in the models folder.

I wonder I need to require or include it for it to realize it exists.